# Group checkbox in Antd by using array object

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, antd

Here is the original example of group checkbox of `antd` that I need and its fine:

```
const plainOptions = ['Apple', 'Pear', 'Orange'];
const defaultCheckedList = ['Apple', 'Orange'];

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    checkedList: defaultCheckedList,
    indeterminate: true,
    checkAll: false,
  };

  onChange = checkedList => {
    this.setState({
      checkedList,
      indeterminate: !!checkedList.length && checkedList.length < plainOptions.length,
      checkAll: checkedList.length === plainOptions.length,
    });
  };

  onCheckAllChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      checkedList: e.target.checked ? plainOptions : [],
      indeterminate: false,
      checkAll: e.target.checked,
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div style={{ borderBottom: '1px solid #E9E9E9' }}>
          <Checkbox
            indeterminate={this.state.indeterminate}
            onChange={this.onCheckAllChange}
            checked={this.state.checkAll}
          >
            Check all
          </Checkbox>
        </div>
        <br />
        <CheckboxGroup
          options={plainOptions}
          value={this.state.checkedList}
          onChange={this.onChange}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

}

My question is how can I replace the `plainOptions` and `defaultCheckedList` by object array instead of simple array and using attribute `name` for this check boxes?
For example this object:

```
const plainOptions = [
  {name:'alex', id:1},
  {name:'milo', id:2},
  {name:'saimon', id:3}
];
const defaultCheckedList = [
  {name:'alex', id:1},
  {name:'milo', id:2}
];
```

I want to use attribute `name` as the key in this example.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I should use "Use with grid" type of group checkbox. It accepts object array. The only think I could do was creating a function that inject "label" and "value" to my object. It makes some duplicates but no problem.

```
function groupeCheckboxify(obj, labelFrom) {
    for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
      if (obj[i][labelFrom]) {
        obj[i]['label'] = obj[i][labelFrom];
        obj[i]['value'] = obj[i][labelFrom];
      }
      if (i == obj.length - 1) {
        return obj;
      }
    }
}

// for calling it:
groupeCheckboxify( myObject , 'name');
```

Comment: Would you happen to know how to use it with the check all functionality? Since this solution no longer uses a local state to work with the checkbox group

Answer (score 0):

I'd this same problem and couldn't find any answer on the entire web. But I tried to find a good way to handle it manually.

You can use this code:

```js
import { Checkbox, Dropdown } from 'antd';
const CheckboxGroup = Checkbox.Group;

function CheckboxSelect({
  title,
  items,
  initSelectedItems,
  hasCheckAllAction,
}) {
  const [checkedList, setCheckedList] = useState(initSelectedItems || []);
  const [indeterminate, setIndeterminate] = useState(true);
  const [checkAll, setCheckAll] = useState(false);

  const onCheckAllChange = (e) => {
    setCheckedList(e.target.checked ? items : []);
    setIndeterminate(false);
    setCheckAll(e.target.checked);
  };

  const onChangeGroup = (list) => {
    if (hasCheckAllAction) {
      setIndeterminate(!!list.length && list.length < items.length);
      setCheckAll(list.length === items.length);
    }
  };

  const updateItems = (el) => {
    let newList = [];
    if (el.target.checked) {
      newList = [...checkedList, el.target.value];
    } else {
      newList = checkedList.filter(
        (listItem) => listItem.id !== el.target.value.id,
      );
    }
    setCheckedList(newList);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setCheckedList(initSelectedItems);
  }, []);

  const renderItems = () => {
    return (
      <div classname="items-wrapper">
        {hasCheckAllAction ? (
          <Checkbox
            indeterminate={indeterminate}
            onChange={onCheckAllChange}
            checked={checkAll}
          >
            All
          </Checkbox>
        ) : null}
        <CheckboxGroup onChange={onChangeGroup} value={checkedList}>
          <>
            {items.map((item) => (
              <Checkbox
                key={item.id}
                value={item}
                onChange={($event) => updateItems($event)}
              >
                {item.name}
              </Checkbox>
            ))}
          </>
        </CheckboxGroup>
      </div>
    );
  };

  return (
    <Dropdown overlay={renderItems()} trigger={['click']}>
      <div>
        <span className="icon icon-arrow-down" />
        <span className="title">{title}</span>
      </div>
    </Dropdown>
  );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the only difference you are talking about making is using an array of objects instead of strings? If that's the case, when looping through the array to create the checkboxes, you access the object attributes using dot notation. It should look something like this if I understand the problem correctly.

```
From CheckboxGroup component:

this.props.options.forEach(el => {
  let name = el.name;
  let id = el.id;

  //rest of code to create checkboxes

  or to show an example in creating components

  let checkboxMarkup = [];
  checkboxMarkup.push(
    <input type="checkbox" id={el.id} name={el.name} key={`${el.id} - ${el.name}`}/>
  );
}
```

'el' in this case refers to each individual object when looping through the array. It's not necessary to assign it to a variable, I just used that to show an example of how to access the properties.

Comment: Yes you undrestood my problem but I did not get where I should put this code?!

Comment: <CheckboxGroup> this is built in module in Atnd that I still want to use it. the options list is a array list and I can not define custom <input> for it